# CSS3: Width and margin transition simultaneously

Tags: html, css

I have two boxes. When clicking a button, the left box is supposed to get smaller and the right box bigger. I am aiming at having a smooth transition. When the right box gets bigger, I want a margin right to be included.

I use CSS3 transition effect. How can I achieve that for the right box the width and margin right transitions happen simultaneously and correctly?

JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/bmzw80py/4/

My code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">   
    <div class="box-left"></div>
    <div class="box-right"></div>
</div>

<button id="animate">Animate</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 40px 0 0 60px;
}

.box-left {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}

.box-left-smaller {
     -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
    width: 355px;
}

.box-right {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100px;
    background: orange;
}

.box-right-bigger {
     -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 1s ease-in-out;

      -webkit-transition: margin 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: margin 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: margin 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: margin 1s ease-in-out;

    width: 62%;
    margin-right: 80px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('#animate').click(function() {
   $('.box-left').addClass('box-left-smaller'); 
   $('.box-right').addClass('box-right-bigger'); 
});
```

Comment: They already do happen simultaneously. You'll have to better define what you mean by "correctly".

Comment: I want both the width and the margin right transitions to appear smoothly and slowly. If I remove the margin part in the .box-right-bigger class, the width transition happens as desired. But how do I achieve that in addition the margin right is set smoothly and not abruptly?

Comment: @max see also my approach below, for a small improvement

Comment: Ah - that judder you're seeing is because you're also changing the div's `float` to `right`, and that's not managed by a transition, it's either/or.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `transition` `margin` first then `width`

```
.box-right-bigger {
     -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;

    width: 62%;
    margin-right: 80px;
}
```

from `.box-right-bigger` class

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmzw80py/10/)**

Comment: But I also want the margin right to be included smoothly. How can I achieve a transition effect there? In your fiddle, the margin right happens abruptly.

Comment: I don't see any difference. There is no smooth or slow process of margin right for the right box.

Comment: but it work for me you can use `all` for both `animation`

Comment: As @Miam84 answering you.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to trigger two different transitions: you might just change the width and the left margin of the left box by applying one class only e.g.

http://jsfiddle.net/4qwrLtuw/1/

---

**CSS** *(all)*

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 40px 0 0 0;
}


.box-right {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
    background: orange;
}


.box-left {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}

.box-left-smaller {
     -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 80px;  
}
```

---

Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use 1 translation for both animations by using `all` instead of 2 declaration (one for width, one for margin):

```
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
```

In your case, the first transition declaration (width) is overriden by the transition for margin...

FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/bmzw80py/11/

Answer (score 0):

Well, you might start out transitioning one or two properties, but then decide to add some others that you want transitioned. So, if the other transition-related values are the same, then it would be much easier to just have the “all” keyword in there from the start, so you don’t have to specify each property in a comma-separated list.

```js
$('#animate').click(function() {
   $('.box-left').addClass('box-left-smaller'); 
   $('.box-right').addClass('box-right-bigger'); 
});
```

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 40px 0 0 60px;
}

.box-left {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}

.box-left-smaller {
     -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    width: 30%;
}

.box-right {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100px;
    background: orange;
}

.box-right-bigger {               
    width: 62%;
    margin-right: 80px;
     -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">   
    <div class="box-left"></div>
    <div class="box-right"></div>
</div>

<button id="animate">Animate</button>
```

```
Here,you find demo
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DhwaniSanghvi/mr1feb5f/